# Detect AudioLayout in AVAssetTrack

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-audio, avasset, core-media

I need to detect number of channels and the format of audio (interleaved or non-interleaved) from AVAssetTrack. I tried the following code to detect the number of channels. As can be seen in the code, there are two ways to detect number of channels. I want to know which one is more reliable and correct, or none of them perhaps (irrespective of audio format)?

```
  if let formatDescriptions = track.formatDescriptions as? [CMAudioFormatDescription],
        let audioFormatDesc = formatDescriptions.first,
        let asbd = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(audioFormatDesc)
    {                                   
       //First way to detect number of channels
        numChannels = asbd.pointee.mChannelsPerFrame 
        
        var aclSize:size_t = 0
        var currentChannelLayout:UnsafePointer<AudioChannelLayout>? = nil
            
        currentChannelLayout = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetChannelLayout(audioFormatDesc, sizeOut: &aclSize)
        
        if let currentChannelLayout = currentChannelLayout, aclSize > 0 {
            let channelLayout = currentChannelLayout.pointee
            
            //second way of detecting number of channels
            numChannels = AudioChannelLayoutTag_GetNumberOfChannels(channelLayout.mChannelLayoutTag) 
        }

}
```

And I don't know how to get audio format details (interleaved or non-interleaved). Looking for help in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `AudioStreamBasicDescription`. All audio `CMFormat`s have one, while  the `AudioChannelLayout` is optional:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/1489137-cmaudioformatdescriptiongetchann?language=objc

> AudioChannelLayouts are optional; this API returns NULL if one doesn’t exist.

Comment: So mChannelsPerframe will always be 2 in AudioStreamBasicDescription, regardless of interleaved or non-interleaved audio?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have wondered why that is the case. Because in case of non-interleaved audio, shouldn't there be one audio channel in one frame?

Comment: It seems screwy, but the situation is actually documented in `CoreAudioBaseTypes.h`, under "Standard AudioFormatFlags Values for AudioStreamBasicDescription" discussion. When you use non-interleaved, the ASBD's "structure and semantic" change. It's very enlightening, I routinely forget this information.